# Trying to write the data into a .txt file - not working

Tags: c#, file-handling

Below is function through which I am writing data into a .txt file. This has worked several times in the past but below code is not working in a way that it doesn't throw any error as such but it doesn't write anything to the file. It just created it and after that even after running code several times, it doesn't work.

Have debugged as well, everything goes smoothly.

```
public void GenerateReportCard()
    {
        string path = @"F:/StudentDetails.txt";
        FileStream fs = null;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
            
        }
        else
        {
            fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);                 
        }
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        foreach (var item in _Student)//_Student is a list of Student class objects
        {
            sw.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", item.StudentName, item.classroom);
            foreach (var marks in item.Marks)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(", {0}", marks);
            }
            sw.WriteLine("\n");
        }
        sw.close();
        Console.WriteLine("student added to .txt file");

    }
```

Comment: `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path)) {` (put the closing `}` just below `Console.WriteLine("student added....`). Get rid of the `FileStream` stuff. This is just a massive improvement suggestion though, as I don't see a reason why your code as presented wouldn't work.

Comment: Or better yet, just use `File.WriteAllLines` - much simpler... but likewise, this looks like it should work. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger? Is it definitely being called? (Just looking, this can't be your actual code - it wouldn't compile at the moment... so maybe the problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown us.)

Comment: That first `if...else` block is pointless, given that the `FileMode` enumeration has `Create` and `OpenOrCreate` fields. Surely one of those would cover your two possible cases.

Comment: I have a feeling that you don't understand what `StreamWriter.WriteLine` actually does. It writes the specified text, followed by a line break. On each iteration of your loop, you write the student's name and classroom followed by a line break, then you write a comma and the mark followed by a line break for each of their marks, then you write a line feed followed by a line break. Does that make sense? I don't think so. I think that the first two `WriteLine` calls should actually be `Write` and the last one should not have an argument. That will write the name, classroom and marks on one line.

Comment: I doubt that this is an issue but you realise that `@"F:/StudentDetails.txt"` should be `@"F:\StudentDetails.txt"`, right?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" actually mean? Is the file created and empty or not created at all?

Comment: @jmcilhinney The file was being created, it just didn't write into it because of the "\" i wrote as "/". Changing this immediately fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must dispose all your streams with 'using'.

You should decide how you will handle exceptions with writing to file (it could be locked, access can be deny to file/folder)

I think you don't need any streams to write to file, you can use StringBuilder with File.WriteAllText().

This works:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information

using System.Text;

var students = new List<Student>
{
    new ("name 1", "class 1", new List<string>{"mark1", "mark2"}),
    new ("name 2", "class 2", new List<string>{"mark3", "mark2"}),
    new ("name 3", "class 3", new List<string>{"mark3", "mark4"}),
};

var reportGen = new ReportGenerator();

reportGen.Prepare(students);
reportGen.GenerateReportCard("D:/StudentDetails1.txt");
reportGen.GenerateReportCard2("D:/StudentDetails2.txt");

public class ReportGenerator
{
    private IEnumerable<Student> _student = new List<Student>();
    public void Prepare(IEnumerable<Student> students)
    {
        _student = students;
    }
    public void GenerateReportCard(string destinationPath)
    {
        var fileMode = FileMode.Open;
        if (!File.Exists(destinationPath))
            fileMode = FileMode.Create;

        using var fs = new FileStream(destinationPath, fileMode, FileAccess.Write);
        using var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        foreach (var item in _student) //_Student is a list of Student class objects
        {
            sw.Write("{0} , {1}", item.StudentName, item.Classroom);
            foreach (var marks in item.Marks)
            {
                sw.Write(", {0}", marks);
            }

            sw.WriteLine();
        }
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("student added to .txt file");
    }

    public void GenerateReportCard2(string destinationPath)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in _student) //_Student is a list of Student class objects
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("{0} , {1}", item.StudentName, item.Classroom);
            foreach (var marks in item.Marks)
            {
                builder.AppendFormat(", {0}", marks);
            }

            builder.AppendLine();
        }

        //will always overwrite text file
        File.WriteAllText(destinationPath ,builder.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("student added to .txt file");
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Classroom { get; set; }
    public List<string> Marks { get; set; }

    public Student(string studentName, string classroom, List<string> marks)
    {
        StudentName = studentName;
        Classroom = classroom;
        Marks = marks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code that works:

```
public void GenerateReportCard()
    {
        string path = @"F:\StudentDetails.txt";
        FileStream fs = null;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
            
        }
        else
        {
            fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);                 
        }
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        foreach (var item in _Student)
        {
            sw.Write("{0} , {1}", item.StudentName, item.classroom);
            foreach (var marks in item.Marks)
            {
                sw.Write(", {0}", marks);
            }
            
        }
        sw.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("student added to .txt file");

    }
```

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP!